# Natural splines in R , ns()

Tags: r, splines

With $K$ knots $(t_1, \ldots, t_k)$ the restricted cubic spline can be written as

$\beta_0 + \beta_1X + \beta_2(X-t_1)^3_+ + \beta_3(X-t_2)^3_+ + \ldots + \beta_{k+1}(X-t_k)^3_+,$

with

$\beta_k = [\beta_2(t_1-t_k) + \beta_3(t_2-t_k)+ \ldots +\beta_{k-1}(t_{k-2} -t_k)] / (t_k -t_{k-1}),$

and

$\beta_{k+1} = [\beta_2(t_1-t_{k-1}) + \beta_3(t_2-t_{k-1})+ \ldots +\beta_{k-1}(t_{k-2} -t_{k-1})] / (t_{k-1} -t_{k}).$

When I specify `glm(y ~ ns(x, df=3, intercept=FALSE), data = data, family = binomial())` in `R` I obtain estimates for:

`ns(x, df=3)1, ns(x, df=3)2, ns(x, df=3)3`

since the intercept should not be included $\beta_0$ is removed. However which is the estimate for my linear term? $\beta_1$. Does the estimate for `ns(x, df=3)1` correspond to $\beta_2$?

Answer (score 4):

Function `ns()` from package **splines** indeed implements a natural cubic spline (aka restricted cubic spline) but using a B-splines basis representation. This provides an equivalent fit but it is not the same as the expansion you wrote in math. This expansion is implemented in function `rcs()` from the package [**rms**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms).